# Get length of string from grep does not work

Tags: bash

I try to get the length of a string like this (bash in linux):

```
VAR= grep "test" file.txt
VARlength= ${#VAR}
```

For some reason the length is always zero, even if the string "test" is inside file.txt

Can someone explain me how to get the length of VAR and what is wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$( )`:

```
VAR=$(grep "test" test.txt)
VARlength=${#VAR}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. don't leave space before and after the `=`
2. you need command substitution: `var=$(command)`

Answer (score 0):

If you like it's also possbile to use [`bc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) and [`wc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/wc-invocation.html) to get the result:

```
VARlength=$(echo "var="$(grep "2" foo | wc -c;)";--var" | bc)
```

This will count the chars inside the match (`wc -c`) and then subtract 1 using bc, because you don't want to count the newline.